# String Matching with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in Python which takes a string and checks if:

1. The last character is a vowel.
2. The last 2 characters are not the same.

This is what I came up with:

```
[aeiou]$
```

Can anybody help me with point number 2: last 2 characters are not the same. For example, `expresso` is valid and `expressoo` is not valid.

Comment: Why not "expressoo"? (By the way, it's "espresso".)

Comment: Huh? The first and last character of "expressoo" are not the same, so that should be valid. Did you mean "oxpresso"?

Comment: @Steve, Sorry i edit it. Have a look again

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to do this without a regular expression.

e.g `if s[-2]!=s[-1] and s[-1] in 'aeiou'`

Comment: The question changed. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: you would want to check for length first, in order to be complete, right?  Something like:  if len(s)>=2 and s[-1]!=s[-2] and s[-1] not in "AEIOUaeiou"

Comment: I have to do it using regular expressions. I have done with that way already. Thank anyway...

Comment: Shouldn't it be s[-2] instead of s[0]?

Comment: The question changed after I answered it. Previously it was required that the first and last characters not be the same.

Comment: oh, I see. but at least 'aeiou' should be 'aeiouAEIOU', right?

Answer (score 2):

```
(?i)([aeiouy])(?!\1)[aeiouy]$
```

**EDIT:**

This is also appealing for not having a repeat:

```
(?i)(?=[aeiouy]{2}$)(.)(?!\1).
```

Comment: (note that you need to escape the backslash when you put it in your sourcecode).>>> re.match("(?i)([aeiouy])(?!\\1)[aeiouy]$", "ao")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x42eca0>
>>> re.match("(?i)([aeiouy])(?!\\1)[aeiouy]$", "oo")
>>>

Comment: `$ perl -le 'print for q(import re), q(print re.compile(r"(?i)([aeiouy])(?!\1)[aeiouy]$").search("paperboy").group(0))' | python` produces the string `oy`.

Comment: @I82Much: You’re trying too hard. :)

Comment: @Ricky2002: Don’t use web sites!!! Try it in your shell where you know WTH’s going on!

Comment: The other solution reminds me of `(?i)(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)(?=.*y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do:

```
r"\w*(?:[^a\W]a|[^e\W]e|[^i\W]i|[^u\W]u|[^o\W]o)\b"
```